# Merge NUnit3 XMLs into one HTML for publishing to Jenkins

Tags: nunit-3.0, extentreports, extent, reportunit

I have multiple testresult.xml (say testresultMachine1.xml, testresultMachin2.xml etc.) that I get by running my nunit3 tests on different machines during a Jenkins pipeline build.

Now, I want to merge these XMLs on the master node and use extent.exe from https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli to generate a single consolidated html report from multiple xmls.

However, I observe that extent.exe creates a separate folder for each testresult.xml e.g. a folder called testresultMachine1, testresultMachine2 and so on, where each of these have their own index.html and dashboard.html.

How can I get a single consolidated index.html and dashboard.html? Is extent.exe the right tool since ReportUnit is being deprecated.

Comment: I would suggest raising a PR to enable merging multiple XML files into 1 using the --merge parameter.

Comment: Opened an enhancement here:  https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli/issues/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but I have raised an enhancement for it here: https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli/issues/6.

*EDIT

Merge is now possible with the --merge arg.